# Why does this range selection method sometimes stop working when used on filtered data?

Tags: excel, filtering, selection, vba

I have a question about the Selection.End(xlDown) range select operation. I'm using a filter on a big set of data and counting how many cells appear after a filter is applied by selecting the first row in the data and then applying this operation to highlight all occupied cells, and then narrowing the count to only visible cells:

```
Range("L3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Set masterfilterrange = Selection

count = Application.count(masterfilterrange)
```

This usually works, but sometimes it doesn't. By stepping through the code I saw that when this code was executed, only the first cell in the visible (filtered) range was selected so the count would only be 1. I tried doing this:

```
Range("L3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Set masterfilterrange = Selection

count = Application.count(masterfilterrange)
```

But it didn't help. I ran the macro on another computer and it went back to working properly.. Does anybody know why it would work at first and eventually start not working?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate what you describe.
This is not really an answer to your question but can't fit it to comments.
What you can do is to explicitly work on your range starting from filter.

Example:

```
Dim r As Range, count As Long
'you can use known ways of dynamically setting this
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:P100") 'L2 have the headers

r.AutoFilter 1, "your_Criteria" 'filter field one using your criteria
'Use Offset and Resize to count L3 to last cell only
count = r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

or if your code serve your purpose

```
count = Application.Count(r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```